# How to retrieve data using minimum number of queries?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq

Here is a sample table and sample class

```
Name    Parameter Value
A1       P1         X
A1       P2         Y
A2       P1         XX
A2       P2         YY

Class foo {
    Int Name
    Int Value1
    Int Value2
}
```

So, how to write a query that should retrieve only rows that have Parameter set to P1 or P2 (there are additional values for Parameter, not showed in the sample)? Also, a query should create List of foo objects with (in this sample case) 2 instances of class foo (one for each distinct Name value).

- foo: Name=A1, Value1=X, Value2=Y
- foo: Name=A2, Value1=XX, Value2=YY

Generated list should also be ordered by Value1.

Thanks in advance.

PV

Comment: `db.Table.Where(x=> x.Parameter=="P1").OrderBy(x=> x.Value).Select(x=> new foo {Parameter=x.Parameter, Value=x.Value}).ToList()`

Comment: I have not properly explained a problem I have (my bad - new to this); it is not that simple (not able to ask 2nd question, so here is clarification). My class has two Value fields: Value1 and Value2 (no need for Parameter field). So, a query should retrieve only rows that have Parameter set to P1 or P2 (there are additional values for Parameter, not showed in the sample). A query should create List<foo> with 2 instances of class foo (one for each distinct Name value). First foo: Name=A1, Value1=X, Value2=Y, second foo: Name A2, Value1=XX, Value2=YY. A list should be ordered by Value1.

Comment: `var result = db.tbl.Where(x=> x.Parameter=="P1").Select(x=> new foo {Name = x.Name, Parameter=x.Parameter, Value=x.Value1}).Distinct().OrderBy(x=> x.Value).ToList()`

Comment: @Rango I have added additional clarification in my comments. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @sriharsha I have added additional clarification in my comments. Sorry for confusion.

Comment: @sriharsha that is not it, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you make your question clear. What you have input data and whats your expected result.

Comment: OK, I will rewrite the question shortly.

Comment: @sriharsha, I have reworded a question.

Comment: Do you want to convert the data to this foo object? thats what your question?

Comment: Yes. a list (as per description, should not have more then 2 elements for specified sample).

Answer (score 0):

I tried like below:
Created a dummy class for input-data:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

---

And in Code,

```
 var inputData = new List<Test>
            {
                new Test{Name ="A1", Parameter="P1", Value="X"},
                new Test{Name ="A1", Parameter="P2", Value="Y"},
                new Test{Name ="A2", Parameter="P1", Value="XX"},
                new Test{Name ="A2", Parameter="P2", Value="YY"}
            };

            var groupedData = inputData.GroupBy(x => x.Parameter).ToList();
            var result = new List<foo>();
            foreach (var item in groupedData)
            {
                result.Add(new foo
                {
                    Name = item.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                    Value1 = item.FirstOrDefault().Value,
                    Value2 = item.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value
                });
            }
```

Output is:
[image: As your expected output]

Comment: Not there yet.. Should be:

foo[0]: Name=A1, Value1=X, Value2=Y
foo[1]: Name=A2, Value1=XX, Value2=YY

In your case it is:

foo[0]: Name=A1, Value1=X, Value2=XX
foo[1]: Name=A1, Value1=Y, Value2=YY

Comment: If you replace:

var groupedData = inputData.GroupBy(x => x.Parameter).ToList();

with

var groupedData = inputData.GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

it works. I am trying to avoid loops. Is there a way to do it without looping?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Table
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Parameter { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class foo
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
}

        var inputData = new List<Table>
        {
            new Table{Name ="A1", Parameter="P1", Value="X"},
            new Table{Name ="A1", Parameter="P2", Value="Y"},
            new Table{Name ="A1", Parameter="P3", Value="Z"},
            new Table{Name ="A2", Parameter="P1", Value="XX"},
            new Table{Name ="A2", Parameter="P2", Value="YY"},
            new Table{Name ="A2", Parameter="P3", Value="ZZ"},
        };

        var groupedData = inputData.Where(y => y.Parameter == "P1" || y.Parameter == "P2" ).GroupBy(x => x.Name).ToList();

        var result = new List<foo>();
        foreach (var item in groupedData)
        {
            result.Add(new foo
            {
                Name = item.FirstOrDefault().Name,
                Value1 = item.FirstOrDefault().Value,
                Value2 = item.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault().Value
            });
        }

        var result1 = result.OrderByDescending(x => x.Value1).ThenBy(x => x.Name);
```

Comment: This is based on answer from @sriharsha, I have added additional logic required in the question. Can this be additionally optimized?